# QWebView open file handles

Tags: qt, qtwebkit

I am trying to make a browser application using QWebView.

I am loading local html in it and even after
closing it ,I observed that fd related to that html page is still opened.
(fuser -m  index.html)

Is QWebview not unloading file and other resources like images etc. when closed ?